# How to dynamically change font size of div and h2 tag after material UI v4 to v5 version upgrade

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, upgrade

I have upgraded the material UI version from v4 to v5, now the font size of a div tag and h2 has been changed which messed up the UI.I am trying to override it using the code mentioned in https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#update-body-font-size. But it isn't working out for me. What am I doing wrong here? I couldn't understand.

I applied the below mentioned code in the theme.js but for some reason it's not working. I was expecting the font size of the content inside div tag should change to 0.875rem but it didn't happen.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        body: {
          fontSize: '0.875rem',
          lineHeight: 1.43,
          letterSpacing: '0.01071em',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```